# How to use formula CASE WHEN on Netsuite Oracle?

Tags: oracle, case, netsuite

Hi Can someone help me with the Saved Search: So I’m trying to create a formula(numeric) that would say:

`CASE WHEN {internalid} = ‘32319’ THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

— didn’t work it didn’t even show on the description

I also tried:

`CASE {internalid} WHEN 32319 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` — also didn’t work and didn’t show on the description.

Not sure if perhaps using formula on my saved search is disabled on my end if so how can I know or check? Or maybe I did not use to correct syntax for the CASE WHEN? The formula is also grayed out(highlighted). [image: NETSUITE_CASEWHEN] [image: NETSUITE SaveSearch]

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a solution. As it turns out I just needed to put a value of 1 on the textbox for Value to validate the CASE WHEN Statement. Also whether there's a single quote for the numbers or in this case without a single quote, it still worked. [image: FormulaNumeric]

Answer (score 0):

Either of those forms should work but your screen shots show a Formula(Text) rather than Formula(Numeric)

Comment: I started out on Formula(Numeric) but after clicking SET it doesn't save it